# problems setting flags from makefile

Tags: c, makefile, flags

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

#ifdef DEBUG
  printf("Debug!\n");
#endif

  printf("hello world\n");

}
```

makefile:

```
CC=gcc-5

CFLAGS=-I

DEPS=foo.c

main: $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -o foo $(DEPS) $(CFLAGS).

debug: CFLAGS += -DDEBUG
debug: main
```

when I run `make debug`

```
gcc-5 -o foo foo.c -I -DDEBUG.
> ./foo 
hello world
```

Why am I not seeing "Debug!"?

Comment: what is that `.` in `-DDEBUG.`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh from the `$(CFLAGS).`

Comment: If I remove it, when I compile using `make` I get `gcc-5 -o foo foo.c -I
gcc-5: error: missing path after '-I'
make: *** [main] Error 1`

Comment: I din't see a reson for `-I` to exist as of now.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, no reason in this example, but the actual project requires it (header files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The`-I` option expects an argument, and right now its `-DDEBUG.`. Either remove the `-I` option, or provide it with an argument. I recommend removing it, since I see nothing that warrants adding a directory to the include search paths.

Comment: This is a super stripped down example. Ah, so the `.` is the argument to `I`?

Comment: @ThemanontheClaphamomnibus It *could* be, but then you need to provided it at the right spot, like `CFLAGS=-I.`.

Comment: Solved! I need the `I` flag, just changed `CFLAGS=-I` to `CFLAGS=-I.`